# Why insert from front of queue (deque)

Tags: data-structures, queue

Are there any reason why people will want to insert something at the front of the queue? I'm writing a report on double-ended queue and this is bugging me.


I'm assuming that maybe something of higher importance will be inserted at the front when needed,  but then a priority queue will be more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example where a deque can be used is Steal job scheduling algorithm.This algorithm implements task scheduling for several processors. A separate deque with threads to be executed is maintained for each processor. To execute the next thread, the processor gets the first element from the deque (using the "remove first element" deque operation). If the current thread forks, it is put back to the front of the deque ("insert element at front") and a new thread is executed. When one of the processors finishes execution of its own threads (i.e. its deque is empty), it can "steal" a thread from another processor: it gets the last element from the deque of another processor ("remove last element") and executes it. The steal-job scheduling algorithm is used by Intel's Threading Building Blocks (TBB) library for parallel programming.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a priority queue is inherently different from a deque, with elements in a PQ being processed according to their priority while in a deque you can only remove and insert at the front or back of the queue. A possible application of a deque I can quickly think of is an "undo" feature enabling you to fall back to a previous state.